# How to select a xpath based on a a sibling number

Tags: html, xpath, siblings

I have a table where i want to select a detail field based on the name.
For example i want to select a detail field based of the first John in the table (that is row 29).

username coll: usercard-table/div/div/div[2]///div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[29]/div/div[3]/div/
details: usercard-table/div/div/div[2]///div[2]/div[2]/div/div[29]/div/div[3]/div/

How can i select the 29th row of the detail field based on a Name?

I have tried to use something like //div[2]/div/div[contains(.,'John)[1]]/div/div[3]/div

Hi for helping out. Hereby a simple example of the code. I want to select the div with the class="cell-icons-after-text based on the 2e John (div\div\div[3])

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div>

            </span>
                <span name="indicators" class="cell-icons-after-text">
                </span>
                <span name="value" class="cellText">
                    <span class="ui-grid-cell-contents-value"><span name="data">John</span></span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div>

            </span>
                <span name="indicators" class="cell-icons-after-text">
                </span>
                <span name="value" class="cellText">
                    <span class="ui-grid-cell-contents-value"><span name="data">Will</span></span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div>

            </span>
                <span name="indicators" class="cell-icons-after-text">
                </span>
                <span name="value" class="cellText">
                    <span class="ui-grid-cell-contents-value"><span name="data">John</span></span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>

            </span>
                <span name="indicators" class="cell-icons-after-text">
                </span>
                <span name="value" class="cellText">
                    <span class="ui-grid-cell-contents-value"><span name="data">John</span></span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div>

            </span>
                <span name="indicators" class="cell-icons-after-text">
                </span>
                <span name="value" class="cellText">
                    <span class="ui-grid-cell-contents-value"><span name="data">Will</span></span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div>
            </span>
                <span name="indicators" class="cell-icons-after-text">
                </span>
                <span name="value" class="cellText">
                    <span class="ui-grid-cell-contents-value"></span>
                </span>
            </span>
        <div>
            </span>
                <span name="indicators" class="cell-icons-after-text">
                </span>
                <span name="value" class="cellText">
                    <span class="ui-grid-cell-contents-value"></span>
                </span>
            </span>
        <div>
            </span>
                <span name="indicators" class="cell-icons-after-text">
                </span>
                <span name="value" class="cellText">
                    <span class="ui-grid-cell-contents-value"></span>
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a simple html example code?
You can try wildcars:
`//*[contains(text(),'John')]`
(i add the second quote missing in your example)
And if you have 29 elements that you can non distingate, so:
`(//*[contains(text(),'John')])[29]`